# How to Fetch Data From Postgresql Database using Flask And Display HTML Tables

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

```
  import psycopg2
    from flask import Flask, render_template
    app = Flask(__name__)
    con = psycopg2.connect(database="Angels_Attic", user="postgres", password="", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
    cursor = con.cursor()

    @app.route("/", methods=['post', 'get'])
    def test():  
        cursor.execute("select * from cart")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        return render_template("test.html", data=result)
```

test.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        {% for row in data %}
        <p>{{ row[0] }}</p>
        <p>{{ row[1] }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Error I'm getting :
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

When I run this flask file, I'm getting bunch of errors. I just want to know how to connect the database properly and fetch data from it with complex SQL queries and display it in the HTML file. Please let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing related to the logic of the code, just the indentation of the code should be like this:
remove the spaces from all the lines below import

```
import psycopg2
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
con = psycopg2.connect(database="Angels_Attic", user="postgres", password="", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
cursor = con.cursor()

@app.route("/", methods=['post', 'get'])
def test():  
    cursor.execute("select * from cart")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template("test.html", data=result)
```